# Continuous b'\xff'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I want to make a game with Python 3.6 and I have a problem. When I try to set conrols(like WASD), the Python Shell detect that I constantly press ÿ (unicode: b'\xff'). I have not ÿ on my keyboard. I wrote:`print(getch())` and `print(chr(ord(getch())))`.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the solution to my problem?
2. What is the best method to set controls in game made with Python?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could it be an `EOF` return code `-1` (`0xFF` if you try to make it into a char), signaling the end of input, that you're interpreting as a unicode sequence? This is certainly a control signal, not actual keyboard input. If you're using Curses, take a lookt at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241366/getch-returns-1

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I was using IPython console included in Spyder. Here are my suggestions:

First, try to use ***cmd*** console to check if the problem continues.

Second, `getch()` does not wait for you to press a key and continuously reads. If you need to capture a few specific inputs you may need to use:

```
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        ch = msvcrt.getch()
        print(ch)
```

Third, since you got bytes and you may want to check against few characters in your code, my suggestion for Windows is to use `getwch()` instead of `getch()`. Here is my code that logs characters with the time they have been pressed:

```
import msvcrt, sys, datetime
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        ch = msvcrt.getwch()
        if ch == 'q':
           sys.exit()
        else:
           print (ch, " Pressed at : ", datetime.datetime.now().time())
```